# How do I program a parallel keyboard input

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parallel-processing, keyboard

As written before, I would like to know how parallel keyboard input works.

This is my code so far:

```
cout << "Enter time for Key A: ";
cin >> timeA;
cout << "Enter time for Key B: ";
cin >> timeB;
while (1)
{

    Sleep(timeA);
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; // Specify the key as a unicode character
    ip.ki.wScan = 'A'; // Which keypress to simulate
    ip.ki.wVk = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));


    Sleep(timeB);
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; // Specify the key as a unicode character
    ip.ki.wScan = 'B'; // Which keypress to simulate
    ip.ki.wVk = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

}
```

It works, but I would like to reach, that e.g. the Letter A is being pressed every 500ms and the Letter B is pressed every 1s. How would I do that?

Comment: A hint: Do you know how the modulo operator works? For example, if you have an ever increasing counter, and use e.g. `counter % 500` or `counter % 1000`, what would be the result of that?

Comment: Or learn about *threads*.

Comment: or you can sleep for 500 press A, sleep for 500 press B. This way A will be always pressed after 500 ms and B will be pressed always after 1s in a loop if my brain is functioning properly. I'll post a code that may help you too.

Comment: "or you can sleep for 500 press A, sleep for 500 press B" @TuğberkKaanDuman this will press A and B with interval of 1 second

Comment: I meant wait 500ms (now we're at 0.5s), press A. wait 500ms (now we're at 1s), press B. My logic may be broken now, I'm not feeling good today. @KillzoneKid

Comment: You have to follow up by `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` to simulate key up. Windows provides `SetTimer` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a timer class. You can create an object and call it like:

```
timer timer_1(time_in_milliseconds, true_if_async, &function_name, argument_1, arg_2, ...);
```

This way you can run your functions after a certain amount of time has passed, you can run multiple functions together with async as well or just use sync and queue them. Your choice.

Threads is the best solution for your problem.

```
class timer
{
public:
    template <class Callable, class... Arguments>
    timer(int after, const bool async, Callable&& f, Arguments&&... args)
    {
        std::function<typename std::result_of<Callable(Arguments...)>::type()> task(bind(forward<Callable>(f), forward<Arguments>(args)...));

        if (async)
        {
            thread([after, task]()
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(after));
                task();
            }).detach();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(after));
            task();
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a small example usage:

```
void say(const string& word)
{
    cout << "Hello, " << word << "!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        timer timer1(500, false, &say, "pyreN - A");
        timer timer2(1000, false, &say, "pyreN - B");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you have follow up questions do ask @pyreN and if this solves your problem don't forget to click the green tick next to the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Do I have to make a constructor and destructor for that class? @ Tuğberk Kaan Duman

Comment: You don't have to make a destructor but you can. Constructor is already there for you. `timer(int after, ...` I'll edit the answer and will add a small example on usage.

Comment: @pyreN check my latest edit, now since it's set to false it'll run each after one runs. I've just realised 500, 500 would be more appropirate but anyway, that may give you some idea.

Comment: Okay thank you so much ! If there are no arguments to use, should I leave it open or what to do? @ Tuğberk Kaan Duman

Comment: Leave it like this: `timer timer1(500, false, &say);` from 4th and beyond parameters, it's all for arguments. If you don't have any, don't enter any. @pyreN

Comment: roger that! thanks again I guess this solved my problem!  @ Tuğberk Kaan Duman

Comment: one more question, which libraries do I need to include? coz i have tons of errors xd  @ Tuğberk Kaan Duman

Comment: `#include <functional>` `#include <chrono>` `#include <thread>` I'll update the code to make it suit working without `using namespace std` now. @pyreN

Comment: When I set both times to 500 and 1000 i receive an error: Debug Error! Programm test_app.exe 

abort() has been called!

(Press Retry to debug the application)

Comment: Can you paste the code you're trying on https://hastebin.com/ press save and send me the new link? @pyreN

Comment: @pyreN it was probably giving error abort() because we're in while(1) and it's hard on CPU. Here's a smaller example: https://hastebin.com/oyogolarog.cpp

Try now with 500, 1000.

Comment: Well it works but its not parallel. and if I choose true the program stops. It waits 500ms and sends A then wait 1000ms and sends B and so on.

Comment: When you make it true, it actually runs but for some reason it runs extremely quick. I'll post you an example output.

Comment: @pyreN since console disappears fairly quickly that's the best shot I could get before it dies. https://i.imgur.com/eAggq3r.png Each thread took only 0.0005 seconds, that's weird behaviour, I'll try to solve it and will update you once I'm finished.

Comment: wow thats fast xd thank you so much for the effort! @ Tuğberk Kaan Duman

Comment: @pyreN I've written from complete scratch. This time it works as intended. https://hastebin.com/ecokaforih.cpp I've set 10 seconds and 5 seconds, run the program watch your clock and see yourself. They won't block each other and B will print after 5 sec, 5 sec later A will print. You can adjust the time (in ms) to anything.

Comment: is there a way to convert this program into an .exe file from visual studio community?

Comment: Press CTRL + F5. It will compile the file to `.exe`, Open your project location from Windows Explorer. If you did `CTRL + F5` in `Debug | x86` for example, go to `C:\path_to_project\project_name\Debug` you'll find `project_name.exe` inside that file. That's your `.exe`.

Comment: okay but i cant run the .exe due to lack of some dll files, i guess thats another problem right?

Comment: It shouldn't ask for any extra dll files if you didn't include in your project. You can check your project settings under `Project -> `your_project Properties...`. That's a different problem, but easily solveable too. Download missing DLL files and put in same folder with that `.exe`, it shouldn't ask for it though.